# Make "aptitude" automatically choose solution "Install" instead of "Keep"

Tags: aptitude

I'm trying to automatically install packages without asking user any questions. For the below situation, `aptitude` chooses "Keep" as the *first* solution, and doesn't install **pkg_b**. And I want to force `aptitude` to select the "Install" solution and upgrade **pkg_a**.

```
$ sudo aptitude install -y -f --no-gui --without-recommends \
    -o Dpkg::Options::='--force-confnew' \
    -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes \
    pkg_a=1.1 pkg_b=1.2

The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pkg_b{b}
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pkg_b : Depends: pkg_a (= 1.2) but 1.1 is installed.

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     pkg_b [Not Installed]
```

If I manually (without `-y`) run above command, and then answer `.` (`.`: move to the next solution), **aptitude** suggests another solution:

```
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:
1)     pkg_b [1.2 (stable)]

     Upgrade the following packages:
2)     pkg_a [1.1 (now, stable) -> 1.2 (stable)]
```

So this solution is best for me.

Answer (score 2):

Worked solution, is to add this parameter:

```
-o Aptitude::ProblemResolver::SolutionCost='100*canceled-actions,200*removals'
```

Found by looking at [this](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s03s04.en.html) manual. How it works - we just increase the costs of solutions which `aptitude` will be use:

- Do not *keep*, if you can *install* or *upgrade* (by increasing `canceled-actions` counter)
- Increase `removals` counter, because we want keep pkgs if `aptitude` decide to *delete* it

Comment: This guy also has problem like me [Russian]:http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/general/10882881